# How to remove part of textbox text in VBA powerpoint?

Tags: vba, formatting, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation with subtitles in white and yellow text in 1 textbox per slide (white is up, yellow follows). I would like to replace white text with a white dot ("."). Do I need to make a variable and make it count white characters and delete from front?

This is my script so far:

```
Sub RemoveWhiteText()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape


    With ActivePresentation

For Each oSl In .Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                    If TextRange.Font.Color = vbWhite Then
                        oSh.TextFrame.Text
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, you have to loop through the collection of chars untill selected text is white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read my comment to the question. I suggested there to loop through the collection of chars till the color of font is white.

Try this:

```
Sub RemoveWhiteText()

Dim oSl As Slide, oSh As Shape, oTr As TextRange, i As Long

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                Set oTr = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
                i = 1
                Do While oTr.Characters(1, i).Font.Color = vbWhite
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
                'MsgBox oTr.Characters(1, i - 1).Text
                If i > 1 Then oTr.Characters(1, i - 1).Text = "."
                Set oTr = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej Los! Worked!

For some reason it crashed my ppt but when I recovered the white text was gone :)

Comment: You're very welcome, Michał ;) Pozdrowienia z Białegostoku! Cheers, Maciej

Answer (score 0):

Each text block of distinct formatting is a Run. In your case, the first run has font color white. You can use that info to run a loop as follows:

```
Sub StripLeadingWhiteText()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim rn As TextRange2

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
           If shp.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                Set rn = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Runs(1)
                If rn.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite Then
                    rn.Text = "."
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub`
```